# Actions on Google perform operation in local network

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Trying to create an action on Google that communicates with devices in my local network.

So my question is, is that even possible, to perform an operation directly through google home, without a need to have a webhook in a server somewhere??

and if so, and i will need to have a webhook, what is the best way to make the webhook communicate with my phone, other than push notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control anything on your home network then you will have to run the fulfillment server in your house or let an external fulfillment server connect to something in your house. Either way you will need to poke a hole on your home firewall or use something like ngrok or bst proxy.

Then you will be in your home network and you can do your things on your local devices.

You should be more specific about the communication with your phone. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?